# Dispatcher.Invoke() not invokes specified delegate

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispatcher

Method **MethodForThread()** works in a different thread and at the end he has to call back method **AsyncCallbackMethod()** in the thread in which was called the method **MethodForThread()**. I do it with class Dispatcher. But the fact is that **Dispatcher.Invoke()** does not call this method **AsyncCallbackMethod()**. What am I doing wrong that it does not work?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace EventsThroughDispatcher
{
    class Program2
    {
        public delegate void AsyncCallback();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "MainThread";

            Thread thrdSending = new Thread(MethodForThread);
            thrdSending.Name = "WorkingThread";
            ThreadParameters tp = new ThreadParameters();
            tp.DispatcherForParentThread = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            tp.SendingCompleteCallback = AsyncCallbackMethod;
            Console.WriteLine("Start");
            thrdSending.Start(tp);

            while (!Console.KeyAvailable) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        static private void AsyncCallbackMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Callback invoked from thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }

        static void MethodForThread(object threadParametersObj)
        {
            ThreadParameters tp = (ThreadParameters)threadParametersObj;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            tp.DispatcherForParentThread.Invoke(tp.SendingCompleteCallback, null); //this not working
            //tp.DispatcherForParentThread.BeginInvoke(tp.SendingCompleteCallback, null); //and this not working too
            Console.WriteLine("WorkingThread exited");
        }

        private class ThreadParameters
        {
            public Dispatcher DispatcherForParentThread;
            public AsyncCallback SendingCompleteCallback;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using the WPF dispatcher, but I can't see anything creating any WPF controls etc. Are you sure there even *is* a dispatcher?

Comment: I thought CurrentDispatcher would create a new one if there isn't one, but can a Dispatcher even do anything during Thread.Sleep?

Comment: Jon Skeet, that is, in the console application Dispatcher will not work?

Comment: @AnatoliiGumennyi: No, it won't. There's nothing trying to pump it. There's just the main thread, which you're in control of. In general, console apps using anything under System.Windows is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution won't work in this form. The Dispatcher object can be used for make a changes on the UI in nutshell(you can pass an action to the dispatcher and it pass to the message-driven WIN32 API, to execute the changes on the UI).

If you debug your code you can see the Dispatcher.HasStarted flag is false, so it won't pass anything to the UIThread.

I recommend you to use the Asynchronous design patter.

You can find the implementation here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14898/Asynchronous-design-patterns

Answer (score 2):

You have one definitive problem:

```
 while (!Console.KeyAvailable) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
```

this will block any dispatcher running. But you seem to use this in a Console App, I'm not sure if that will ever work. A dispatcher needs a 'message pump'.